# While uploading videos using Uploadify most of time get 500 internal server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, file-upload, passenger, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to upload videos using uploadify to my ubuntu Aws server, but I get a HTTP error 500 most of the time.

I checked every apache setting, and also tried to change the execution time to 1200, the upload max to 300mb, I changed the sizelimit to 200MB, I tried to change modsecurity in the .htaccess file, the problem was not there.

This error is not very frequent.If i start getting 500 internal server error, then it keep coming while uploading videos.I got dead ends with most of the sites I visited.
I check all security related issue as well. Everything works fine then sometime it behaving very unexpectedly.

When i start uploading video using Uploadify. The video keep getting upload and this error 500 internal server error comes when uploading reached to 100%. In apache error log it shows this error

> [ pid=5222 thr=139968009692928 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:884 time=2013-06-05 07:19:29.465 ]: Unexpected error in mod_passenger: An error occurred while receiving HTTP upload data: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
>     Backtrace:
>        (empty)

My Server and application configuration are -:

- Ruby version => 1.93
- Rails => 3.28
- Uploadify => 3.1
- Apache => 2.4.4
- Passenger => 3.0.19

Below is my uploadify script:

```
    <% session_key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] %>
    var uploadify_script_data = {};
    var token_id= $(".swingAnalysisBanner").attr("rel");
    var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');
    uploadify_script_data['_http_accept'] = 'application/javascript';
    uploadify_script_data[csrf_param] = csrf_token;//encodeURI(encodeURIComponent(csrf_token));
    uploadify_script_data['<%= session_key %>'] = '<%= cookies[session_key] %>';
    $('#Uploadify').uploadify({
        multi  : false,
        method      : 'post',
        swf         : '<%= asset_path("uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.swf") %>',
        uploader    : '/token/'+token_id+'/videos.json',
        formData    : uploadify_script_data,
        fileObjName   : 'attachment',
        fileTypeExts : '*.mov; *.flv; *.mp4; *.avi; *.mkv; *.wmv; *.mpg; *.MOV; *.FLV; *.MP4; *.AVI; *.MKV; *.WMV; *.MPG',
        fileSizeLimit : '50MB',
        fileTypeDesc : 'Video Files',
        wmode     : 'transparent',
        auto      : true ,
        buttonText : 'Select',
        buttonClass: 'uploadBtn',
        width: 320,
        height: 75,
                    onSelect: function(fileObj){
                    },
        onSelectError: function(file, errorCode, errorMsg){
                        var ext = file.name;
                        ext = ext.substr(ext.length-4).toLowerCase();
                        switch(errorCode){
                            case -130:
                              this.queueData.errorMsg = "File extension: " + ext + " is not allowed." + '\n' + "Try one of the following file extensions:" + '\n' + "mov, flv, mp4, avi, mkv, wmv, mpg";
                        }
        },
        onUploadSuccess : function(file, data, response)
        {

        },
        onUploadStart: function(file){
            // this is to show only uploading progress bar when upload gets started
            $("#Uploadify").uploadify('disable', true);
            if(!(/8.0|9.0|10.0/.test(ieInspector.ieVersion)))
                $("#Uploadify").css("visibility", "hidden");
            else
                $("#Uploadify-button").css("display", "none");
            $(".uploadText").css("display","none");
            $(".uploadHeading").css("display","none");
            $(".mobileView").css("display","none");
        },
        onCancel : function(file){
            // following block cancels the upload
            alert('The file ' + file.name + ' was cancelled.');

        },
            onUploadError : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                //Only showing following alert if error is other than cancel of file upload

            }
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=354).

Some people report having success (in Mac OS X with Safari) by disabling keepalive in Apache. The Phusion guys think it has something to do with a long-standing Safari bug (maybe WebKit bug?) or a network error.

Give it a try.